# Android permission: Phone Calls, is it dangerous?

Tags: android

When installing an app, I saw this "Phone Calls" permission most of the time:

**PHONE CALLS**

**READ PHONE STATE AND IDENTITY
Allows the application to access the phone features of the device. An application with this permission can determine the phone number and serial number of this phone, whether a call is active, the number that call is connected to and the like.**

Is this dangerous and can be misused by rogue app?

I meant, how far can it be dangerous? Especially about the "IDENTITY" part.

Note that this permission is not the same as:

**SERVICES THAT COST YOU MONEY**

**DIRECTLY CALL PHONE NUMBERS
Allows the application to call phone numbers without your intervention. Malicious applications may cause unexpected calls on your phone bill. Note that this does not allow the application to call emergency numbers.**

Which can cause the app to initiate phone call (and can be abused to call costly service number).

Thanks.

Comment: I think this is more a question for http://android.stackexchange.com/

Comment: because in this world there is a term used in common now a days, **identity theft** :) By the way, what are you implementing and what problem are you facing for this while coding?

Comment: If someone has my phone number, how it can be used to dial other phone number and cost me money? Note that this permission is not the same as "CALL PHONE" permission which the app can initiate phone call.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This application can call seme costly service number providing revenues to rogue  developer. You carrier will happy to syphon your money to him (well, your carrier gets fair cut of it), and you will have to prove that there was fraud.  Is it dangerous enough?

Comment: I don't think this permission can call another phone number, because it is not the same as "CALL PHONE" permission.

Answer (score 2):

I've been wondering a lot about this too. I believe that this permission should not be granted to games and other apps that dont need to know your phone number.

Breaking it down:
An application with this permission

1. can determine the phone number
   Your number could be sold to third parties who can then send you unsolicited text messages or phone calls
2. and serial number of this phone, 
   Why the heck they (app developers) need the serial number of your phone? Tracking?
3. whether a call is active, 
   Tracking?
4. the number that call is connected to and 
   Tracking?
5. the like
   Not sure what this means but sounds very vague.

I dont want to sound like a paranoid but Google needs to break this permission into various parts so that legitimate applications can be given the right permissions.